# CSS HTML: center table on bottom (%-width, with max-width specified)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This was asked previously in the wrong section, so I removed and am reposting it now.

How would I go about centering a div with a %-based width which also has a `max-width` specified on the bottom of the page?

I can center it on the bottom of the page if I remove the max-width style, but it breaks as soon as I try to specify it.

Any help with this would be fantastically appreciated as this is the last hurdle my app faces before I can wrap it out and get it out. :D

EDIT:

As is almost always the case, in trying to clean up my source for posting, I had a last-minute idea and voila, it worked.

```
            string docText =
            @"<!DOCTYPE html><html>
            <style type=""text/css"">
                table { 
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 100%; 
                    word-break: keep-all; 
                    word-wrap: break-word; 
                    overflow: hidden; 
                    }

                table td { 
                    border: 0px; 
                    word-break: keep-all; 
                    word-wrap: break-word; 
                    vertical-align: top; 
                    padding: 2px 8px; 
                    }

                div.inner { 
                    margin-left: auto; 
                    margin-right: auto; 
                    //border: dotted red 1px; 
                    max-width: 800px; 
                    }

                div.outer {
                    width: 98%;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    //border: dotted black 1px;
                    }

                </style>
            <script>
                function addRow(text1, text2) {
                    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
                    var tr=document.createElement(""TR"");

                    var td=document.createElement(""TD"");
                    td.innerHTML = text1; 
                    td.align = ""right"";
                    td.valign=""top"";
                    tr.appendChild(td);

                    td = document.createElement(""TD"");
                    td.innerHTML = text2;
                    td.style.wordBreak=""keep-all"";
                    td.style.wordWrap=""break-word"";
                    tr.appendChild(td);

                    tbody.appendChild(tr);
                    }
                </script>

            <body><div class=""outer""><div class=""inner""><table>

            <colgroup>
                <col style=""width: 60px; align: right; vertical-align: top;"">
                <col style=""width: 90%; align: left; vertical-align: top; "">

            </colgroup>
            <tbody id=""tbody""> 

            </tbody></table></div></div></body></html>";
```

Comment: Is that all you have in your html? Post code.

Comment: post the code or create fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to horizontally centre a div that has a percentage width, as well as a max-width, using margins:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Will horizontally adjust the left and right margins depending on the size of the parent container.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SfSwa/

Answer (score 0):

For starters your table that you have given is not showing anything, and you have double quotes around all your classes and ID's, i suggest you check if your editor is adding the second automatically.

I would say you wrapping div needs to be "margin:auto;" too allow it to adjust to the sides and thus sit in the center for you.

```
.inner {
    margin: auto;
    //border: dotted red 1px;
    max-width: 800px;
   }
```

Here is a JSFiddle with smaller width to allow demonstration in the Demo box.

http://jsfiddle.net/wrzNS/

Also tables are inherently bad for applications and smaller devices, I would suggest you have a look into only using divs which are more responsive with less work.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Comment: The very first line is `string docText = @"`.  It's a C# string, they have to be doublequoted.   Rows are inserted at runtime via the script.

Comment: My bad, are you passing it back as HtmlString then or as a string ?
anyway its still based on your CSS being incorrect.